# How to custom Spring Batch DelimitedLineTokenizer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have two file types to insert in database.

Format are : aa;bb;cc and aa;bb;cc;dd;ee

This is my FlatFileItemReader :

```
    <bean name="readerContractToAddIntoPRV" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="comments" value="#" />
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
        <property name="strict" value="false" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="net.wl.batchs.fieldSetMapper.LineToCreateIntoPrvFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
                        <property name="names" value="aa,bb,cc,dd,ee" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I want a setup that works for both types of files.

For the moment, I have this :

> org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException:
>   Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 3 actual 5

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you.

Edit : After correction :

```
<bean name="readerContractToAddIntoPRV" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="comments" value="#" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" /> 
    <property name="strict" value="false" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper" p:lineTokenizer-ref="multilineFileTokenizer">
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="net.wl.batchs.fieldSetMapper.LineToCreateIntoPrvFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multilineFileTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer">
  <property name="tokenizers">
    <map>
      <entry key="*;*;*;*;*" value-ref="NSCE_ICCID_MSISDN_LOGIN_PWD"/>
      <entry key="*;*;*" value-ref="NSCE_ICCID_MSISDN"/>
      <entry key="*" value-ref="headerDefault"/>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="parentLineTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer" abstract="true">
    <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
</bean>
<bean id="NSCE_ICCID_MSISDN_LOGIN_PWD" parent="parentLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="nsce,iccid,msisdn,login,pwd" />
</bean>
<bean id="NSCE_ICCID_MSISDN" parent="parentLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="nsce,iccid,msisdn" />
</bean>
<bean id="headerDefault" parent="parentLineTokenizer">
    <property name="names" value="nsce,iccid,msisdn" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue isn't your tokenizer.  What you'll have to do is use the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper.html).  This will allow you to create a pattern for each line type you have and associate it with the appropriate `LineTokenizer`.

You can see this `LineMapper` in action in our samples here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/multilineOrderInputTokenizers.xml

Comment: I have another question.
Your solution works, but analyzes each line. How to check only the tokenizer corresponds with the header ? (and not with each line).

Comment: There are a number of different ways to handle that depending on how complex you want to get.  The most straight forward would be to implement your own equivilant of the `PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper` that only does the evaluation once.

Comment: For your information, I use the HeaderBasedDelimitedLineTokenizer class. (Exactly what I was looking). I found it here:https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1979